jenkins github pr status check pipeline
I want to make a pipeline that performs check when I open PR for "main" branch.

(This picture is a check made through github-action, but there is something I want to make through jenkins pipeline.)
I tried to implement it through a plugin Github Pull Request Builder, but it was not used because it identified a statement that there was a security issue at the moment.
So the next thing I came up with was to make a check that only works with pr through multibranch-pipeline.

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage("PR") {
      when {
        branch pattern: "^PR[-][0-9]*", comparator: "REGEXP"
      }
      stages {
        stage("SomeTest") {
          steps {
            sh "test"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

It was implemented using the when keyword to operate only when it is PR Check.
But I don't like this way, because I thought it didn't fit the purpose of multibranch-pipeline, my pipeline only targets the "main" branch.
So I would like to make a test that execute when I create PR through regular pipeline, not multibranch-pipeline.
Does anyone know how to do it like this?
